# Need help for javascript oops

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

```
var a = function () {};
a.prototype.test  = function () {
alert("hello");
}
```

works fine but in following code

```
var b = new Object();
b.prototype.test  = function () {
alert("hello");
}
```

i am getting this  error TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of undefined and i am unable to get it.

As per my understanding b has inherited prototype object from **Object**. So we should be able to add a new property in following manner say b.prototype.x = 1  .

But **Object**.prototype.x = 1 works .

typeof **Object** and a gives function but that of b is object

I am not getting why b.prototype.x = 1 doesnt work

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` is a function, which has a `prototype` property.

`new Object()` creates an object, which does not have a `prototype` property.

---

If you want to set the prototype of an object, you might mean setting the prototype of the object's constructor.

```
b.constructor.prototype.test = ...
```

---

To clarify some of the prototype/constructor nonsense:

A function has a `prototype`, which is an object. It specifies properties to add to an instance of that function.

An object has a `constructor`, which is a function. It specifies the function that was used to create the object.

Note that a function is an object, so it also has a `constructor`, which is `Function`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky issue -- there are two types of prototype fields, an internal one and an external one.  The external one you can directly access with the normal prototype field as you are doing.  The internal one is used to do lookups when a field/key is not found in the object.

If you do `new blah()`, it creates a new object whose internal prototype field is set to the external prototype field of `blah`.  By default, the external prototype field of the newly constructed object is `undefined`.  In particular, this is why evaluating b.prototype.x fails -- you can't do a field access on an undefined value.  If you wish you can create a new object for a new external prototype, e.g. `b = new Object(); b.prototype = {}`.

You can see the internal/external prototype fields in action here:

```
Object.prototype.x = 4
b = new Object()
b.x // returns 4
```

What's happened is that b's internal prototype field points to Object.prototype, so lookups to b that fail are redirected to do a lookup in Object.prototype.

I'm not sure why, but newly created functions get their external prototype field set to Object -- this causes the first one to work.

Comment: didn't the first one work because a function inherits Object(), or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: The second one doesn't work because b doesn't have an external prototype field at that point.  I think you're right about the first one working because a newly created function gets Object set as its external prototype field.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [resource](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html)

It doesn't work for the new object because it doesn't have a `prototype` property set. `prototype` property points to the Object that you have inherited. And since `new Object()` has had no object to inherit from, its `prototype` is set to `undefined`

A `function` on the other hand, has a super object (it inherited) by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
var b = {};
b.test = function() {
    alert('Hello');
};
```

Comment: You haven't answered the question of why it isn't working the way the OP has it.